# Jest mocking multiple files and static methods

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am trying to write a test case using Jest. How can I write the test case for below snippets? A is a separate file and Three is a different file. I need to write the test cases as separate files as like unit test cases.

I am stuck in writing the static methods calling and mocking the multiple inputs. See below what I have tried also.

```js
const one = require('../one');
const two = require('../two');
const three = require('../three');

class A {
  public static checkTesting(param) {
    switch (param) {
      case 'one':
        return one;
      case 'two':
        return two;
      default:
        return three;
    }
  }
  constructor(param) {
    this.testing = A.checkTesting(param);
  }
}

module.exports = A;
```

```js
const multiple = require('../multiple')(module);
const config = require('../config');
class Three {
  public static sampleTestingWrite() {
    return {
      b: param => multiple[config.access](param)
    };
  }
  constructor() {
    this.sampleTesting = Three.sampleTestingWrite();
  }
}

module.exports = Three;
```

`A.test.js`:

```js
const One = require('../one');
const Two = require('../two');
const Three = require('../three');
const A = require('..');
jest.mock('../one');
jest.mock('../two');
jest.mock('../three');

describe('A test cases', () => {
  test('should initiate the constructor', () => {
    const mockStaticFunction = jest.fn();
    mockStaticFunction.mockReturnValue('returns an object which does something on Multiple');
    const MockA = new A('one');
    console.log(MockA);
    Console.mockImplementation(() => ({}));
    console.log(logMedium);
    expect(Console).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if the constructor of `A` is called correctly. There is no need to mock `one`, `two`, `three` modules. Only you need to mock/spyOn is 
`checkTesting` static method of `A`.

Here is the solution, I use typescript

```
import one from './one';
import two from './two';
import three from './three';

class A {
  public static checkTesting(param) {
    switch (param) {
      case 'one':
        return one;
      case 'two':
        return two;
      default:
        return three;
    }
  }
  private testing;
  constructor(param) {
    this.testing = A.checkTesting(param);
  }
}

export { A };
```

Unit test:

```
import { A } from './a';

describe('A', () => {
  describe('checkTesting', () => {
    it('should initiate the constructor', () => {
      jest.spyOn(A, 'checkTesting').mockReturnValue({ name: 'never mind' });
      const param = 'one';
      const a = new A(param);
      expect(a).toBeInstanceOf(A);
      expect(A.checkTesting).toBeCalledWith(param);
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/mock-function/57624975/a.spec.ts
  A
    checkTesting
      ✓ t1 (8ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |    73.33 |        0 |    66.67 |    73.33 |                   |
 a.ts     |    66.67 |        0 |    66.67 |    66.67 |         7,9,11,13 |
 one.ts   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 three.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 two.ts   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.649s, estimated 3s
```